# Exporting jpeg around polygon boundary using Python?

Tags: arcpy, export

I have a python code that goes through my map document and exports a jpg for each polygon grid.  Right now it clips the image to the boundary of the each polygon.

Does anyone know how I can make it clip a small amount of data around the grid?

I only want a 1-2% more added but I'm not sure if this can be added to my existing code or do I have to create new polygons that are all a small amount bigger so I can capture this extra data.

Below is the code I am using right now.

```
import arcpy
... mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\markd\OneDrive\Documents\GIS\PalmSprings\PalmSprings_TileExport.mxd")
... df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Layers")[0]
... lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"L8_PS")[0]  ##shapefile layer name called grid
... rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(lyr)
... x=1
... for row in rows:
...     df.extent = row.Shape.extent
...     arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, r"C:\GIS\PalmSprings\L8_PS\ " + str(row.getValue("PageName")) + ".jpg", df, df_export_width = 1200, df_export_height = 1200, resolution = 96, world_file=True, jpeg_quality = 100)
...     print x
...     x+=1
... del mxd
```

Answer (score 4):

I used to do this by modifying the scale of the data frame:

```
...
for row in rows:
    df.extent = row.Shape.extent
    df.scale = df.scale * 1.02
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(...)
    ...
```

You might need to play a bit with the scaling factor to find the extent that suits you (1.02 is probably a bit low).